# Design a Pi Filter

Tags: filter

I would like to understand the usage of Pi filters more while design rather than just in theory.

I have gone through this [TI App Note for Input Filter design](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva538/snva538.pdf) and it doesn't provide any clarity.

Could someone explain me how to choose the values of Pi Filter (L & C) in any design and what parameters does this L & C values depend on? Should Pi Filters be placed in Input or Output side and what benefits does it have?

Please provide clarity.

Thanks

Comment: How you design a filter depends what you're using it for. The app note you linked to is specifically about designing a filter for use at the input of a switching power supply (DC-DC converter). Is that what you want to design a filter for?

Comment: Also, you might notice that none of the filters in that app note are pi filters.

Comment: I would like to understand for Switching power supplies

Comment: The app note deals with the input filter to a SMPS. If you were designing an audio filter, an RF filter, or a SMPS output filter, you'd have different criteria. Find an app note that's relevant to the job you want your filter to do.

Comment: PI filters depend strongly on what input impedance and what output impedance you need to work with, and if you **WANT** a resonant behavior or if resonance is **BAD**.